# Existe algum erro de sintaxe nesse código em php?

Tags: php

Sou iniciante ainda em php, aqui vai o codigo, aqui ta dando erro de sintaxe

```
<?php
function conexao(){ 
  $banco = "curosphp_mysql";
  $usuario = "root";
  $senha = "";
  $host = "localhost";
  mysqli_select_db($conn, $banco);  
}
 conexao();
?>
```

Update:

```
<?php 
function conexao(){ 
    $banco = "curosphp_mysql";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $banco); 
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $banco); 
} 

conexao();
?>
```

Comment: `$conn` não existe no escopo da função e outro problema futuro ... sua função não retorna valor (a conexão em especial).

Comment: Bom, a variável `$conn`, que em `mysqli_select_db` não existe, então sim, existe o erro.

Comment: $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

Comment: esse codigo resolve o porblema?

Comment: agora ta dando o erro que ta dando um } inesperado, por favor me ajudem

Comment: Como está seu código?

Comment: <?php
function conexao(){ 
  $banco = "curosphp_mysql";
  $usuario = "root";
  $senha = "";
  $host = "localhost";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
  mysqli_select_db($conn, $banco);  
}
 conexao();
?>

Comment: A documentação tem exemplos completos de como fazer, tanto procedural quanto OOP: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php - documentação é feita pra isso mesmo, pra ler, pra aprender, pra estudar, e duvidas mais especificas que fogem ao uso basico das APIs traga aqui para o site, veja exemplo de conexão procedural explicado na doc: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.construct.php#example-1784

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa de `mysqli_select_db($conn, $banco);` se não for mudar de banco de dados.

```
<?php 
    function conexao(){
        $host = "localhost";
        $usuario = "root";
        $senha = "";
        $banco = "curosphp_mysql";

        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

        // Não precisa do código abaixo, porque você não está trocando de banco de dados
        // mysqli_select_db($con, $banco);

        return $con;
    } 

    conexao();
```

Comment: muito obrigada, deu certinho :)